# Как писать спецификацию API в Swagger editor?

Tags: openapi

Есть ли где-то информация как писать спецификацию API в Swagger editor. Не понимаю где писать параметры методов. Где можно посмотреть пример спецификации?

Comment: вопрос про swagger2 или про openapi(swagger3)?

Comment: вопрос про openapi

Comment: речь об [этом](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/#:~:text=Here%20is%20a%20more%20detailed%20example%20with%20parameters%20and%20response%20schema)?

Comment: кажется да)) спасибо))

Comment: Если у нас у параметра есть несколько вариантов значений, эти значения мы пишем в дескрипшене? Или как то еще можно задать?

Comment: зависит от конктерной ситуации. ищи в документации `enum`, `oneOf`, `anyOf`, `allOf`

Comment: спасибо! А есть ли какая то логика для выбора кодов ошибок?

Comment: конечно есть. можешь погуглить best practices (например https://habr.com/ru/post/351890/), но нужно понимать, что "код ошибки" - это сообщение для приложения, подразумевающее какую-то реакцию приложения или изменение состояния приложения. так что можешь использовать любой приглянувшийся статус из 4хх, лишь бы приложение обработало этот статус так, как должно. собсно, в swagger ты должен описать формат сообщения для каждого используемого статуса

Comment: ну, можно и не расписывать, а ограничится schema->type->object, но перспективнее прописать :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Еще есть вопрос когда я открываю Swagger Editor вся страница у нас под 1 API? Или под 1 модуль?

Comment: и что такое для понимая paths?

Comment: "и что такое для понимая paths?"  по той же ссылке, поднимись выше на пару экранов